# Tracking Visits on a Roll Up Account with Google Analytics Universal

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, change-tracking

I am just looking for some help setting up a single view of all the sites we have. I can find lots of help for the old analytics tracking code but not for the new universal analytics.

I've got 5 sites each with their own tracking code in place but i'd like to create a roll up account that allows me to look at an overview of all the sites in a single view. Just wondering what i need to add to the code to do this?

It's currently;

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXX', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

And I would just like to know what i need to add in to be able to include the numbers in a roll up account too? I think it's possible to simply edit this code with the UA of the roll up account but I'm not sure of the correct way to format this.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks
Roxi

Answer (score 1):

It works rather like it did with asynchronous analytics, only you pass the name of the tracker in the (optional) configuration object:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', {
   'name': 'firstTracker',

});
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
   'name': 'secondTracker',
});

ga('firstTracker.send', 'pageview');
ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Any other options (e.g cookie domain, which is the third parameter if you don't use a configuration object) are set as key-value pairs in the configuration object. You find this in the [documentation under Advanced Configuration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers).

Comment: Thanks - This makes sense i think! So would the actual code (including the original linkid anf display features would be the following.
 

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', {
   'cookieName': 'firstTracker',
   'cookieExpires': 20000 });
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {
   'cookieName': 'secondTracker',
   'cookieExpires': 20000});
  ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

ga('firstTracker.send', 'pageview');
ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');

</script>

Comment: I'm very sorry, I blindly copied and pasted the WRONG example (fixed now) - you need "name" (as in tracker name), not "cookie name". The rest of the code does not the be changed (I do not think you need to reuquire the linkid feature twice - this loads a piece of js which needs to be done only once).